# variable from path from subdir

Tags: batch-file

output from this code is :

```
[ C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Bilder2017\test.jpg ]
[ C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Bilder2017\ ]
[ test.jpg ]
[ test ]
```

how can I get the variable for the dir Bilder2017?

```
@echo off
set dialog="about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject
set dialog=%dialog%('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);
set dialog=%dialog%close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%p in ('mshta.exe %dialog%') do set "file=%%p"
echo [ %file% ]
For %%A in ("%file%") do Set Folder=%%~dpA
echo [ %Folder% ]
for %%i in ("%file%") do set "isoname=%%~nxi"
echo [ %isoname% ]
for %%i in ("%file%") do set "name=%%~ni"
echo [ %name% ]
pause
```

Comment: You realize you could set all those variables in the first `FOR /F` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For %%A in ("%folder%.") do Set "leaf=%%~nxA"
```

which treats the name in `folder` as a filename and gets the last part.

Comment: Good. You should "accept" solutions by clicking the tick. If you continue to post questions without accepting responses, you may find responses become rarer.

Comment: Actually, `%%~nA"` will do as the "extension" is always empty.

Comment: @user1016274 : not so in the general case, but maybe in this case. It's possible to have a directory named `Bilder2017.alt` for instance.

Comment: got it! thanks for the explanation. This will even handle multiple dot-delimited pathname parts like e.g. "Bilder2017.alt.jpg".